# I am stumped on this one any help? Rebus

Tags: visual, rebus

Hey all I am extremely stumped on probably such a simple Rebus. Any help here[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably:

> AGE BEFORE BEAUTY
>  H=Age.
>  B four=Before
>  Bee+U+tea=Beauty

Comment: I don't mean to be that guy, but @Apep answered this 11 seconds faster.

Answer (score 11):

It appears to be:

> Age before beauty
>
>  "H" = Age (rough pronunciation)
>  B+4 = Before
>  Bee+u+tea = Beauty